# Cannot find metrics in OpenTSDB - Caused by: net.opentsdb.uid.NoSuchUniqueName: No such name for 'metrics'

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hbase, opentsdb

I try to install and run OpenTSDB in accordance to [the official documentation](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/installation.html) Everything seems to be working fine however when I try to access any metrics from the GUI port 4242 I get errors shown below. I run OpenTSDB using `sudo ./build/tsdb tsd --config=/etc/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf --auto-metric` I have set `tsd.core.auto_create_metrics = true
tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_ts = true
tsd.core.meta.enable_tsuid_tracking = true` in `opentsdb.conf`

```
Caused by: com.stumbleupon.async.DeferredGroupException: At least one of the Deferreds failed, first exception:
    at com.stumbleupon.async.DeferredGroup.done(DeferredGroup.java:169) ~[async-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.stumbleupon.async.DeferredGroup.recordCompletion(DeferredGroup.java:142) ~[async-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.stumbleupon.async.DeferredGroup.access$000(DeferredGroup.java:36) ~[async-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.stumbleupon.async.DeferredGroup$1Notify.call(DeferredGroup.java:82) ~[async-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1278) ~[async-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1257) ~[async-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.callback(Deferred.java:1005) ~[async-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.HBaseRpc.callback(HBaseRpc.java:720) ~[asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:1575) ~[asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:88) ~[asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.handleUpstream(RegionClient.java:1230) ~[asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.messageReceived(SimpleChannelHandler.java:142) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelHandler.handleUpstream(IdleStateAwareChannelHandler.java:36) ~[netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:294) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$RegionClientPipeline.sendUpstream(HBaseClient.java:3857) ~[asynchbase-1.8.2.jar:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.opentsdb.uid.NoSuchUniqueName: No such name for 'metrics': 'tsd.'
    at net.opentsdb.uid.UniqueId$1GetIdCB.call(UniqueId.java:380) ~[tsdb-2.3.1.jar:eca1ef4]
    at net.opentsdb.uid.UniqueId$1GetIdCB.call(UniqueId.java:377) ~[tsdb-2.3.1.jar:eca1ef4]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I am having the same issue and I have properly defined properties in opentsdb.conf file. Can you help me how did you resolve this?